# Multiple Parameters issue in SQL Server Stored Procedure and Nest JS API

Tags: sql-server, nestjs

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[API_Insert_Break]
@EmployeeId int,
@BreakTypeTitle nvarchar(200)=null,
@UpdationIP varchar(20)=null,
@Reason nvarchar(200)=null,
@BreakInIP nvarchar(50)=null,
@BreakOutIP nvarchar(50)=null



as begin

    if (@BreakOutIP is null)
        begin

            INSERT INTO AttendanceBreaks(AttendanceId, 
                                         BreakTypeId, 
                                         StartAt, 
                                         BreakInIPAddress, 
                                         Reason,
                                         CreationDate,
                                         CreatedBy,
                                         UpdationIP)
            VALUES ((select top 1 Id from Attendances where EmployeeId=@EmployeeId order by Id desc), 
                    (select BreakTypes.Id from BreakTypes where BreakTypes.Title=@BreakTypeTitle), 
                    (SELECT convert(time(0),getutcDate())), 
                    @BreakInIP, 
                    @Reason,
                    getutcdate(),
                    @EmployeeId,
                    @UpdationIP);

        end

    else

        begin

            Update AttendanceBreaks set EndAt=(SELECT convert(time(0),getutcDate())), 
                                        DurationInMinutes=DATEDIFF(minute,StartAt,(SELECT convert(time(0),getutcDate()))), 
                                        BreakOutIPAddress=@BreakOutIP,
                                        UpdationDate=getutcdate(),
                                        UpdationBy=@EmployeeId,
                                        UpdationIP=@UpdationIP
            where Id=(select MAX(Id) from AttendanceBreaks where AttendanceId=(select MAX(Id) from Attendances where EmployeeId=@EmployeeId));

        end

end
```

NestJS service code:

```
    async breakStart(employeeId:number,breakTypeTitle:string,reason:string): Promise<any> {

      var data = await this.sequelize.query(
          'Exec API_Insert_Break :EmployeeId, :BreakTypeTitle, :UpdationIP, :Reason, :BreakInIP',
        {
          replacements: { 
              EmployeeId: employeeId,
              BreakTypeTitle:breakTypeTitle,
              UpdationIP:ip.address(),
              Reason:reason,
              BreakInIP:ip.address()},
          type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
        });
  }








  async breakEnd(employeeId:number): Promise<any> {
    var data = await this.sequelize.query(
        'Exec API_Insert_Break :EmployeeId, :BreakTypeTitle, :UpdationIP, :Reason, :BreakInIP, :BreakOutIP',
      {
        replacements: { 
            EmployeeId: employeeId,
            UpdationIP:ip.address(),
            BreakOutIP:ip.address()
           
        },
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
      });
}
```

The problem is that for the else statement to run, BreakOutIP must not be null. But since BreakOutIP is in the last (declared as a parameter), some of the parameters in between are skipped and it jumps to the last parameter. So if I pass a value to BreakOutIP, that value is not passed to it and as a result, it still runs the first if statement (and not the else statement) which requires BreakOutIP to be null. Because I have heard that **all the parameters passed in the stored procedure must be in the correct sequence and no value should be skipped or it will not run properly**. So can someone please tell how to overcome this problem? I mean how to properly pass parameters so that all input values are read without any confliction?

Comment: *" some of the parameters in between are skipped and it jumps to the last parameter"* This statement makes no sense. CAn you elaborate? Can you provide a full [mre] of the undesired behaviour and explain what behaviour you are expecting?

Comment: Sure. Here is an example: Either a user will start a break or end a break. if he/she starts a break, input parameters are EmployeeId, BreakTypeTitle, UpdationIP, Reason, BreakInIP. Since BreakOutIP is not provided, it is null, hence **if** runs. If user wants to end a break, he/she will input parameters EmployeeId, UpdationIP, BreakOutIP (**skipping BreakTypeTitle, Reason**). So BreakOutIP is provided, it is not null. So **else** must run. But due to sequence issue (values skipped), it's value is not read.

Comment: Again, provide a [mre]. At a guess, you using ordinal parameters to `EXECUTE` your procedure and think that SQL Server has some way of guessing what parameters you want it to parse them as; it doesn't.  If your parameters are optional, and may be omitted, don't use position parameters.

Comment: Then what parameters should I use instead of position parameters? can you kindly tell?

Comment: `EXEC dbo.YourProc @SomeParam = {YourValue}, @AnotherParam = {AnotherValue}, ...`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Problem is that the parameters sequence of Nest JS code and Stored Procedure must be the same. No parameter must be skipped in the Nest JS code. So I passed **null** values to the remaining parameters and it worked fine.

```
  async breakEnd(employeeId:number): Promise<any> {
    var data = await this.sequelize.query(
        'Exec API_Insert_Break :EmployeeId, :BreakTypeTitle, :UpdationIP, :Reason, :BreakInIP, :BreakOutIP',
      {
        replacements: { 
            EmployeeId: employeeId,
   ------>  BreakTypeTitle:null,
            UpdationIP:ip.address(),
   ------>  Reason:null,
   ------>  BreakInIP:null,
            BreakOutIP:ip.address()
           
        },
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
      });
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using named parameters in your query, instead of ordinal parameters, so that you wouldn't need to send the "extra" parameters with null values? i.e.: `'Exec API_Insert_Break @EmployeeId=:EmployeeId, @UpdationIP=:UpdationIP, @BreakOutIP=:BreakOutIP'`